# Rename files based on their parent directory in Bash

Tags: bash, find, rename

Been trying to piece together a couple previous posts for this task.
The directory tree looks like this:

```
TEST
   |ABC_12345678
       3_XYZ
   |ABC_23456789
       3_XYZ
   etc
```

Each folder within the parent folder named "TEST" always starts with ABC_\d{8} -the 8 digits are always different.  Within the folder ABC_\d{8} is always a folder entitled 3_XYZ that always has a file named "MD2_Phd.txt".  The goal is to rename each "MD2_PhD.txt" file with the specific 8 digit ID found in the ABC folder name i.e. "\d{8}_PhD.txt"

After several iterations on various bits of code from different posts this is the best I can come up with,

```
cd /home/etc/Desktop/etc/TEST
find -type d -name 'ABC_(\d{8})' |
find $d -name "*_PhD.txt" -execdir rename 's/MD2$/$d/' "{}" \;
done
```

Comment: is `3_XYZ` folder always of static name for all files?

Comment: Yes, that folder is always named 3_XYZ within ABC.

Comment: `find` will accept multiple directories as starting points, so `find $( find -type d -name 'ABC_(\d{8})' ) -name "*_PhD.txt" -execdir rename 's/MD2$/$d/' "{}" \;`  (no `done` required). might work, unless there are spaces in your file or dir names that you're not showing here. Don't have time to test. Other answers look *slightly* more straightfoward ;- ).  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution:

```
find -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/TEST/ABC_[0-9]{8}/3_XYZ/MD2_Phd\.txt" \
-exec bash -c 'abc="${0%/*/*}"; fp="${0%/*}/";
 mv "$0" "$fp${abc##*_}_PhD.txt" ' {} \;
```

---

Viewing results:

```
$ tree TEST/ABC_*
TEST/ABC_12345678
└── 3_XYZ
    └── 12345678_PhD.txt
TEST/ABC_1234ss5678
└── 3_XYZ
    └── MD2_Phd.txt
TEST/ABC_23456789
└── 3_XYZ
    └── 23456789_PhD.txt
```

Comment: I didn't see this at first for some reason...I will try this as well, thank you @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: Very nice solution as well!  Thank you to both of you - these two approaches will be helpful for slight modifications for other issues that arise.

Answer (score 2):

You are piping `find` output to another `find`.  That won't work.

Use a loop instead:

```
dir_re='^.+_([[:digit:]]{8})/'
for file in *_????????/3_XYZ/MD2_PhD.txt; do
  [[ -f $file ]] || continue
  if [[ $file =~ $dir_re ]]; then
    dir_num="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    new_name="${file%MD2_PhD.txt/$dir_num.txt}" # replace the MD2_PhD at the end
    echo mv "$file" "$new_name"                 # remove echo from here once tested
  fi
done
```

Comment: Impressive, works like charm seamlessly! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad it worked! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)